# Bluetooth LE Scan filter MAC address often not working for all the list

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon

My app scans for bluetooth devices. I would like filtering the scan by a list of MAC address. With Samsung S7 Android 8.0 that works always well.

But I have problem with others devices as Xiaomi Android 8 and Honor Android 7.
When I start the scan, often I haven't possibility to get all Bluetooth devices MAC listed in the filter.
Stop/Start scan : Sometimes I get only the one MAC adress. 
Stop/Start scan : Then I get all.
Stop/Start scan : Then I get only the one and the third...

Please where is the problem? 
I would like get an error when I call startscan if the writing filter has fail.
Or is it possible to flush or reset the filter?

```
BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBluetoothLeScanner = manager.getAdapter().getBluetoothLeScanner();
ArrayList<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();        

ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .build();

String[] filterlist = {
                    "AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA",
                    "BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB",
                    "CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC",
};

for (int i=0; i< filterlist.length ; i++) {
    ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(filterlist[i]).build();
    filters.add(filter);
    Log.v("Filter: "," "+ filters.get(i).getDeviceAddress());
}

Log.d(TAG, "filters" + filters );       

mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mLeScanCallback);
```

Comment: Can you show how you stop and restart the scan?

Comment: It's inside a service, the start is how I show in the last post:
mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mLeScanCallback);
And the stop, also inside the service:
mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);

Comment: To complete my last post, start is inside onStartCommand() and stop inside onDestroy() of a service.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code in context, but my concern is that the `.stopScan` is either not being called consistently, or it is not consistently being called before the next `startScan` is called.